# How to Handle Multiple, Related State Management Classes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-getx, riverpod

I have a Flutter app that uses an SQLite database that has lots of inter-dependent tables. So far I have used Provider to create a class for each table in my database. The classes rely on each other and need to know when some of the others update.

I have added all 23 of my providers to `main.dart` using `MultiProvider`. I'm finding that Provider won't allow me to access `ClassA` from `ClassB` which is a deal-breaker.

I am considering a few options:

### Option 1 - Riverpod

This tool allows me to make different groups of data aware of each other, but the downside is a lot of extra code. You have to create an entire `StateNotifierProvider` just to watch a single list of data. The learning curve feels steep, too.

```dart
//One of these for every single reactive data list + other provider types for other data types
class ClassANotifier extends StateNotifier<List<DataType1>> {
  ClassANotifier(): super([]);
  ...
}
```

### Option 2 - GetX

There is an enormous amount of debate about GetX, but I'm trying to ignore all of that. It seems that GetX controllers allow me to reference other controllers anywhere I want. It appears this would solve my problem (but potentially bring unwanted side-effects that the internet is raging about).

```dart
class ControllerA extends GetxController {
  var controllerB = Get.put(ControllerB());
}

class ControllerB extends GetxController {
  ...
}
```

### Option 3 - Single, Monolithic Provider Class

I recently learned that I can break a Dart `class` up across multiple files like this:

```dart
//=== class_a.dart ===
part 'class_b.dart';

class ClassA with ChangeNotifier {
  ...
}
```

And then in the other files:

```dart
//=== class_b.dart ===
part of 'class_a.dart';

extension ClassB on ClassA{
  ...
}
```

This would approach would allow me to use Provider to have a single class I put in my widgets, and I can access any part of my data structure across my app. I would have to be careful to name things clearly, but otherwise it seems like it could work.

Is there another way to handle lots of inter-dependent data like this in my app's state?

Answer (score 0):

GetX is talked about a lot, but when you work with it, you fall in love. I use it in all my projects, they are not projects for large companies, but for many screens (50 to 100).
It's very simple and its learning curve is smooth!
I use it and will continue to use it!!!

Screen A -> Screen B -> Screen C (in B and C you have access to A controller) when close A, GetX down A Controller!! (this optimizes memory usage!!)