# Riverpod 2 - Flutter - Single State Class for multiple widgets (instances)

Tags: flutter, riverpod, freezed, flutter-freezed, riverpod-generator

This might be a simple solution for others, but I have honestly been struggling (for almost 2 months now) trying to get this `Riverpod 2` Code Strategy to work. I've looked at other questions here on SO (like -> [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76080892/3002719), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73325121/3002719), and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76809658/3002719)) but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this code solution for some reason :(.

### **Here is the code strategy**:

> **1. I have a freezed model (`TruZapBtnMDL`) class that defines all the properties for the custom button (`TruZapBtn`) widget class.**
> **2. I have a Business Logic Code (`TruZapBtnBLC`) class that manages all the ***business logic and state*** for the `TruZapBtn` widget [intrinsically].**
> **3. Finally -> I want to implement this logic where I create and maintain 3 distinct `TruZapBtn` widget objects using only the **"key" property** [argument] passed during the class (widget) initialization.**

Please see my code logic (attempts) below ...

##### 1. MODEL Class ...

```
@freezed
class TruZapBtnMDL with _$TruZapBtnMDL {   //* <- Defines the 'Tru Zap Button' Freezed Model - MDL.
  factory TruZapBtnMDL({
    required Key key,
    required bool isEnabled,
    required bool isPressed,
    required bool isLockDown,
    required bool isInitBuild,
    required Color colorLocked,
    required Color colorPressed,
  }) = _TruZapBtnMDL;
}
```

##### 2a. STATE Class ...

```
@riverpod
class TruZapBtnBLC extends _$TruZapBtnBLC {   //* <- Defines the 'Tru Zap Button' Business Logic Code - BLC.

  @override
  TruZapBtnMDL build() {
    return TruZapBtnMDL(
      isEnabled: true,
      isPressed: false,
      isLockDown: false,
      isInitBuild: true,
      key: const Key('TZB_BLC'),
      colorLocked: Colors.amber,
      colorPressed: Colors.blueAccent,
    );
  }

}
```

##### 2b. BUTTON (Widget) Class ...

```
class TruZapBtn extends ConsumerWidget {   //* <- Defines the actual 'Tru Zap Button' Widget (GUI).

  //* Class Properties ...
  @override final Key key;
  final Color colorPressed, colorLocked;
  final bool isEnabled, isPressed, isLockedDown, isInitBuild;

  //* Class Constructor ...
  const TruZapBtn({
    this.isEnabled=true,
    this.isPressed=false,
    this.isInitBuild=true,
    this.isLockedDown=false,
    this.colorLocked=Colors.amber,
    this.key=const Key('TruZapBtnGUI'),
    this.colorPressed=Colors.blueAccent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  //* Instantiate the 'TruZapBtnBLC' State Provider ...
  static TruZapBtnBLC _blcTZB = TruZapBtnBLC();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    //* 1. Link Provider to ensure realtime GUI updates ...
    ref.watch(truZapBtnBLCProvider);

    //* 2. Read NOTIFIER - only once !!!
    if(_blcTZB.isInitBuild) {
      _blcTZB = ref.read(truZapBtnBLCProvider.notifier);
      _blcTZB.isInitBuild = false;
    }

    //* 3. Build modular TruZapBtn Widget [with intrinsic BUSINESS CODE LOGIC] !!!
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      onTapUp: (TapUpDetails tuds) {},
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails tdds) {},
      child: Container(
        color: _blcTZB.state.isLockDown
                ? colorLocked
                : colorPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

##### 3. IMPLEMENTATION Code ...

```
TruZapBtn tzbBtn01 = TruZapBtn(key: Key('TZB01'));

TruZapBtn tzbBtn02 = TruZapBtn(key: Key('TZB02'));

TruZapBtn tzbBtn03 = TruZapBtn(key: Key('TZB03'));
```

Right now the code implementation above does not create 3 unique state trackers/providers for each of the 3 distinct buttons (as intended), but simply creates a single state tracker/provider that changes the state in all 3 buttons simultaneously when any one of the 3 buttons are pressed.

So how do I ensure that only the state of the 2nd button is updated when `tzbBtn02` is pressed - and likewise for the other buttons?

I trust the code explains my problem better than my actual word explanation.

Comment: Have you tried using `.family` modifier and passing the key as the parameter?

Comment: Propose a code solution and let me see how it works dude. Please ensure to use the `Riverpod 2` Code-Gen approach as shown in the problem code example above. @DhafinRayhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies in how you're handling state with Riverpod. In your current implementation, all buttons share the same instance of `TruZapBtnBLC`. If you want each button to have its own state, you need to create separate providers for each button or use an identifier to distinguish each instance.

Here's a solution using a Family provider with Riverpod:

Modify your provider to use ProviderFamily:

```
final truZapBtnBLCProvider = Provider.family<TruZapBtnBLC, Key>((ref, key) => TruZapBtnBLC(key: key));
```

Update the `TruZapBtnBLC` class to accept a key:

```
class TruZapBtnBLC extends StateNotifier<TruZapBtnMDL> {
  final Key key;

  TruZapBtnBLC({required this.key})
      : super(TruZapBtnMDL(
          key: key, // => Add this !
          isEnabled: true,
          isPressed: false,
          isLockDown: false,
          isInitBuild: true,
          colorLocked: Colors.amber,
          colorPressed: Colors.blueAccent,
        ));

  // For example, a method to toggle the button press state could look like this:
  void togglePressed() {
    state = state.copyWith(isPressed: !state.isPressed);
  }
}
```

In your widget `TruZapBtn`, use this provider with the key:

```
class TruZapBtn extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Color colorPressed, colorLocked;
  final bool isEnabled, isPressed, isLockedDown;

  const TruZapBtn({
    required Key key,
    this.isEnabled = true,
    this.isPressed = false,
    this.isLockedDown = false,
    this.colorLocked = Colors.amber,
    this.colorPressed = Colors.blueAccent,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // Link to the provider using the key to get the specific state for this button
    final blc = ref.watch(truZapBtnBLCProvider(key));

    // Now, use the state from the BLC directly
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        blc.togglePressed(); // For example
      },
      child: Container(
        color: blc.state.isLockedDown ? colorLocked : colorPressed,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You no longer need the isInitBuild logic and the instantiation of TruZapBtnBLC in your widget. You can remove those parts.

You can now create each button with a unique key, and each button will have its own state managed by the provider:

```
TruZapBtn tzbBtn01 = TruZapBtn(key: Key('TZB01'));
TruZapBtn tzbBtn02 = TruZapBtn(key: Key('TZB02'));
TruZapBtn tzbBtn03 = TruZapBtn(key: Key('TZB03'));
```

Using a ProviderFamily allows you to create a separate instance of your BLC for each unique key you provide. Thus, each button will have its own state, independent of the other buttons.